# What does "up to complex signs" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I'm studying the SVD, but I'm confused about the term "up to complex signs"

*If A is square and the singular values are distinct, the left and right singular vectors are uniquely determined up to complex signs*

For example, I know that the term can applied to 2 - i and 2 + i.
But can it be applied to 2 and -2?

What exactly does "up to complex signs" mean? Can negation to not only complex part but also entire number be allowed?

Comment: It means up to multiplication by a complex number of modulus $1$. The last paragraph in this [subsection of the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Singular_values,_singular_vectors,_and_their_relation_to_the_SVD) makes this a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

*Up to complex signs* seems to me like it would mean some property holds for any complex numbers of the same modulus, as you could interpret *complex sign* as simply a rotation in the complex plane. Thus the complex sign of a number $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ would simply be $\frac{z}{\lvert z\rvert}$. Thus, if your property holds for $z=re^{i\theta}$, then it holds for any number $re^{i(\theta+\phi)}$ for arbitrary $\phi$.